# Detect a specific range of correlated variable

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix  and it is 100 row by 16 column , I am trying to find the correlation coefficient of the 100 variable (row) and select the rows with 0.3 and -0.3 correlated variable, I  used the code bellow :

```
  X=xlsread('data1.xls');
  [R,P]= corrcoef(X');
```

R is a symmetric matrix ( 100x100) , how can I specify the variable which with 
   0.3 and -0.3 correlation.

Comment: How do you define the correlation of a 1D array?

Comment: Correlation is defined for a row _with respect to another_, if I understand correctly. There is no such thing as "rows with a 0.3 to -0.3 correlated variable", unless you specify with respect to which other row

Comment: Iam sorry I could not figure out what you mean by ( unless you specify with respect to which other row)     what i mean is if i have 100 row then when i select the rows by cutoff 0.3and -0.3 then the row will decrease to 50 for example

Comment: You have `R` of dimension [16, 16]. Something like `[row, col] = find(R>0.3);`. Then `index = [row, col]` will give you the index (variables from 1 to 16)  where the correlation coefficient is > 0.3.

Comment: The R dimension is [100,100] , and and i used find i am confused hoow can i specify the variable (row  ) with R = 03 ??

Comment: Ha sure, it's `R'` transposed - didn't see it. If `find` is too tricky, you can copy paste R in Excel and search for the >0.3 (double click on R too edit it in Matlab). Otherwise, `unique(rows)` will give the unique variable indexes.